# RegEx in Notepad++ to find lines with less or more than n pipes

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a large pipe-delimited text file that should have one 3-column record per line. Many of the records are split up by line breaks within a column.

I need to do a find/replace to get three, and only three, pipes per line/record.

Here's an example (I added the line breaks (`\r\n`) to demonstrate where they are and what needs to be replaced):

```
12-1234|The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.|Every line should look similar to this one|\r\n
56-7890A|This record is split\r\n
\r\n
on to multiple lines|More text|\r\n
09-1234AS|\r\n
||\r\n
\r\n
56-1234|Some text|Some more text\r\n
|\r\n
76-5432ABC|A record will always start with two digits, a dash and four digits|There may or may not be up to three letters after the four digits|\r\n
```

The caveat is that I need to retain those mid-record line breaks for the target system. They need to be replaced with `\.br\`. So the final result of the above should look like this:

```
12-1234|The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.|Every line should look similar to this one|\r\n
56-7890A|This record is split\.br\\.br\on multiple lines|More text|\r\n
09-1234AS|\.br\||\.br\\r\n
56-1234|Some text|Some more text\.br\|\r\n
76-5432ABC|A record will always start with two digits, a dash and four digits|There may or may not be up to three letters after the four digits|\r\n
```

As you can see the mid-record line breaks have all been replaced with `\.br\` and the end-of-line line breaks have been retained to keep each three-column/pipe record on its own line. Note the last record's text, explaining how each line/record begins. I included that in case that would help in building a regex to properly identify the beginning of a record.

I'm not sure if this can be done in one find/replace step or if it needs to be (or just should be) split up into a couple of steps.

I had the thought to first search for `|\r\n`, since all records end with a pipe and a `CRLF`, and replace those with dummy text `!@#$`. Then search for the remaining line breaks with `\r\n`, which will be mid-column line breaks and replace those with `\.br\`, then replace the dummy text with the original line breaks that I want to keep `|\r\n`.

That worked for all but records that looked like the third record in the first example, which has several line breaks after a pipe within the record. In such a large file as I am working with it wasn't until much later that I found that the above process I was using didn't properly catch those instances.

Comment: I'd rather fix the text in Python. If you can open the file in NPP, it is good to be processed with Python. It will be easy to match 3 pipe-separated columns and then replace `\r\n`s inside the extracted rows.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thanks, but I don't even know how to do that - use Python, that is...

Comment: Well, to replace those line breaks, you might try `(?:\G(?!^(?<!.))|^\d{2}-\d+[A-Z]*\|[^|]*?(?:\|[^|]*?)?)\K\R` and replace with ``\\.br\\``

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that worked on all but the third record (09-1234AS). It kept the two last `CRLF`s

Comment: But those are outside the fields. That is just a blank line. `Edit` > `Line Operations` > `Remove Empty Lines`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
(?:\G(?!^(?<!.))|^\d{2}-\d+[A-Z]*\|[^|]*?(?:\|[^|]*?)?)\K\R+
```

Replace with `\\.br\\`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qE6l3k/1). *Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!^(?<!.))|^\d{2}-\d+[A-Z]*\|[^|]*?(?:\|[^|]*?)?)` - either the end of the previous match (`\G(?!^(?<!.))`) or (`|`) start of a line, two digits, `0`, one or more digits, zero or more letters, a `|`, then any zero or more chars other than `|`, as few as possible, and then an optional sequence of `|` and any zero or more chars other than `|`, as few as possible (see `^\d{2}-\d+[A-Z]*\|[^|]*?(?:\|[^|]*?)?`)
- `\K` - omit the text matched
- `\R+` - one or more line breaks.

See the Notepad++ demo:

[image]

If you need to remove empty lines after this, use `Edit` > `Line Operations` > `Remove Empty Lines`.